# Angularjs flicker on refreshing the ui often

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

Let's suppose I have a template like this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{text}}</p>
```

And I have a controller that refresh this content every second:

```
function($scope){

    $scope.title = "Flicker";
    $scope.text = "Each time I refresh";

    setInterval(function(){
        $scope.title = "Flicker";
        $scope.text = "Each time I refresh";
        $scope.$digest();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then my UI is flickering which is visually annoying. (Also It prevents someone to copy-paste for example). However my content is not changing at all, so it shouldn't be updated and mess with the ui. So is there an automatic way to prevent it? I found myself doing a lot of:

```
if($scope.title != title)
    $scope.title = title;
```

Which is not really nice, especially when the content is an array or an object.

Thank you

Comment: What browser are you using and what else is in your UI? - the snippet above works flicker-free on Chrome and Firefox when added to a fairly simple page. I presume your function is actually: function myController($scope){ ...

Comment: You are right, I can not reproduce the flicker effect I had. Probably I was pushing an array in the scope the wrong way. Thank you for having spent some times on it. I'll edit my question with more details if I experience the problem again.